# Issue starting Chaquopy PythonConsoleActivity

Tags: python-3.x, android-studio, chaquopy

I am trying to use python scripts in an android project(java).  My end goal is to run face_recognition console scripts, so I have started with the PythonConsoleActivity demo from Chaquopy. https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy-console
I have created a PythonActivity.java (that resembles the MainActivity.java template from chaquopy)

```
package com.projectdevelopment.faces;

import android.app.*;
import com.projectdevelopment.faces.python.PythonConsoleActivity;

public class PythonActivity extends PythonConsoleActivity {

    @Override protected Class<? extends Task> getTaskClass() {
        return Task.class;
    }

    public static class Task extends PythonConsoleActivity.Task {
        public Task(Application app) {
            super(app);
        }

        @Override public void run() {
            py.getModule("main").callAttr("main");
        }
    }
}
```

I have the main.py file stored in src/main/python as advised by Chaquopy.
[image: Project Structure]

```
from six.moves import input


def main():
    print("Enter your name, or an empty line to exit.")
    while True:
        try:
            name = input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        if not name:
            break
        print("Hello {}!".format(name))
```

I have configured the project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:8.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.chaquo.python'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.projectdevelopment.faces"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        python{
            buildPython "C:/Python38/python.exe"

            //staticProxy "main.py"
            pip{
                install "six"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
        sourceSets{
            main{
                python{
                    srcDirs = ["src/main/python"]
                }
            }
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //***********************ADDITIONAL DEPENDENCIES************************
    implementation 'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.13.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'
    //**********************************************************************
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I run the App, I am using a button from the mainActivity to start the PythonActivity as follows:

```
 python.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent pythonActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PythonActivity.class);
                startActivity(pythonActivity);
            }
        });
```

When the python button is clicked a Fatal Exception occurs stating: Cannot create instance of class (see below)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.projectdevelopment.faces, PID: 4286
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projectdevelopment.faces/com.projectdevelopment.faces.PythonActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.projectdevelopment.faces.PythonActivity$Task
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.projectdevelopment.faces.PythonActivity$Task
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.projectdevelopment.faces.python.ConsoleActivity.onCreate(ConsoleActivity.java:53)
        at com.projectdevelopment.faces.python.PythonConsoleActivity.onCreate(PythonConsoleActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.projectdevelopment.faces.python.ConsoleActivity.onCreate(ConsoleActivity.java:53) 
        at com.projectdevelopment.faces.python.PythonConsoleActivity.onCreate(PythonConsoleActivity.java:20) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chaquopy'
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:973)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._gcd_import(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._call_with_frames_removed(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:961)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._gcd_import(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._call_with_frames_removed(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:961)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._gcd_import(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014)
        at <python>.importlib.import_module(__init__.py:127)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_Python_getModule(chaquopy_java.pyx:154)
        at com.chaquo.python.Python.getModule(Native Method)
        at com.projectdevelopment.faces.python.PythonConsoleActivity$Task.<init>(PythonConsoleActivity.java:54)
        at com.projectdevelopment.faces.python.PythonConsoleActivity$Task.<init>(PythonConsoleActivity.java:49)
        at com.projectdevelopment.faces.PythonActivity$Task.<init>(PythonActivity.java:14)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.projectdevelopment.faces.python.ConsoleActivity.onCreate(ConsoleActivity.java:53) 
        at com.projectdevelopment.faces.python.PythonConsoleActivity.onCreate(PythonConsoleActivity.java:20) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4286 SIG: 9
```

I'm sure I am missing something simple, but I am at a loss.  I am using a 64-bit version of Python3.8.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the contents of [`src/main/python/chaquopy`](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy-console/tree/master/app/src/main/python/chaquopy).